# Partial account from MongoDB via NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Upon viewing the [Mongo Count docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#count), it showed the following code :

```
    // Peform a partial account where b=1
    collection.count({b:1}, function(err, count) {
```

where it count every document that has b:1. Those documents can look something like this

```
{
    a:1,
    b:1,
    c:1
}
```

How can I find the partial account on a more in-depth level. For example consider the following document. How can I count every document that contains 
           `"Name": "LOG-11-05-SH-O1.mp4"` ?

```
   "display": {
     "0": {
       "Name": "LOG-11-05-SH-O1.mp4",
       "Type": "Startup",
       "Count": "2",
       "Detail": {
         "0": {
           "Start": "2013-01-20,11:32:22",
           "End": "2013-01-20,11:32:30" 
        },
         "1": {
           "Start": "2013-01-20,11:32:22",
           "End": "2013-01-20,11:32:30" 
        } 
      } 
    },
     "1": { ....
```

I know that `"display.0.Name" : "LOG-11-05-SH-O1.mp4"` will count everytime `"LOG-11-05-SH-O1.mp4"` appears under display 0, but sometimes the number may change. For example, next time time `"LOG-11-05-SH-O1.mp4"` might be under display 1. Thus is there a way to perform a count on only "LOG-11-05-SH-O1.mp4" or perhaps ignore the middle number?

Comment: Can you modify your structure?  Instead of using objects with `0`, `1`, and so forth as keys, could you change `display` to being an array?

Comment: I don't see a way of pulling this off without using an array.  And since your keys are all numbers, this schema is simulating an array but using an object to do so.

Answer (score 1):

See my comments on your question, but I don't see a way to do this without using an array instead of an object for the value of `display`.  If it is an array, this becomes trivial.

Suppose your data looked like this:

```
"display": {[
  {
   "Name": "LOG-11-05-SH-O1.mp4",
   "Type": "Startup",
   "Count": "2",
   "Detail": {
     "0": {
       "Start": "2013-01-20,11:32:22",
       "End": "2013-01-20,11:32:30" 
    },
     "1": {
       "Start": "2013-01-20,11:32:22",
       "End": "2013-01-20,11:32:30" 
    } 
  } 
, { ....}
]}
```

Then you query would just be:

```
db.foos.count({"display": {$elemMatch: { "Name" : "LOG-11-05-SH-O1.mp4"}}})
```

Here is the relevant MongoDB page on $elemMatch: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/.

If you *must* keep the object schema, then you can grab all the records and do the count on the app side and not in MongoDB.

If someone else knows a way to pull this off without the array, I'm happy to receive a downvote and then just remove what would then be an incorrect answer.

Comment: I will test this shortly. Regardless of whether or not this can be done without an array, this doesn't deserve a downvote if it works. It would still be a correct answer, except as an alternative.

Comment: +1 This works nicely. Unfortunately, I have to convert all my data to using arrays. Interestingly enough, if I update, but don't change anything, MongoDB automatically converts 0 , 1 , 2, 3.... into array format.

Comment: That is really interesting.  I'm glad it's of use to you too.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I feel kind of silly not realizing this at first. The answer is quite simple:

`"display.Name": "LOG-11-05-SH-O1.mp4"`

This will find all entries under display that has that following name.